# How to run a stored procedure that lives in SQL Server using AWS Glue

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, aws-glue

I have a stored procedure (`SP_emp`) in SQL Server that runs perfectly and produces an output of 10 rows. Is there a way to run this stored procedure from AWS glue job and the 10 records generated from the stored procedure are saved to an S3 bucket?

I have created a connection to SQL Server using JDBC with a connection string lex1234.

Comment: Side note: You should not name your stored procedures with an "sp_" prefix. See [this article](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix).